# upload and download Button a todo list(like a text file) in js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple todo list and i want to add download function and then upload one. for example  I want to add this functions in a server code.
first of all i want to save my todo-list in a local storage and then upload them and download it.
here is link of my code.
could anybody help me?
https://jsfiddle.net/zahrashokri/uqkn6t3y/3
here is my js code:

````
var todoButton = document.querySelector(".todo-button");
var todoList = document.querySelector(".todo-list");
var filterOption = document.querySelector(".filter-todo");
//Event listeners
todoButton.addEventListener("click", addTodo);
todoList.addEventListener("click", deleteCheck);
filterOption.addEventListener("click", filterTodo);

function addTodo(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var todoDiv = document.createElement("div");
  todoDiv.classList.add("todo");
  var newTodo = document.createElement("li");
  newTodo.innerText = todoInput.value;
  newTodo.classList.add("todo-item");
  todoDiv.appendChild(newTodo);
  var completedButton = document.createElement("button");
  completedButton.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-check"></i>';
  completedButton.classList.add("complete-btn");
  todoDiv.appendChild(completedButton);
  var trashButton = document.createElement("button");
  trashButton.innerHTML = '<i class= "fas fa-trash"></i>';
  trashButton.classList.add("trash-btn");
  todoDiv.appendChild(trashButton);
  var editButton = document.createElement("button");
  editButton.innerHTML = '<i class= "fas fa-edit"></i>';
  editButton.classList.add("edit-btn");
  todoDiv.appendChild(editButton);
  todoList.appendChild(todoDiv);
  todoInput.value = "";
}

function deleteCheck(e) {
  var item = e.target;
  if (item.classList[0] === "trash-btn") {
    var todo = item.parentElement;
    todo.remove();
  }
  if (item.classList[0] === "complete-btn") {
    var todo = item.parentElement;
    todo.classList.toggle("completed");
  }

  //if  (item.classList[0]==="edit-btn"){

  //}

}


function filterTodo(e) {
  var todos = todoList.childNodes;
  todos.forEach(function(todo) {
    switch (e.target.value) {
      case "all":
        todo.style.display = "flex";
        break;
      case "completed":
        if (todo.classList.contains("completed")) {
          todo.style.display = "flex";
        } else {
          todo.style.display = "none";
        }
        break;
      case "uncompleted":
        if (!todo.classList.contains("completed")) {
          todo.style.display = "flex";
        } else {
          todo.style.display = "none";
        }
        break;
    }
  });
}```
````

Comment: I'm sorry, but you didn't describe what you need help with. Currently this feels more like you're offering us a programming exercise. You can find the localstorage api here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: i want that after my todo list saved in a local storage then upload the list and download it from what i uploaded again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to be able to write Upload or Download functions on a website, we must use this object and its methods. The following website will be useful to read more about this
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest.
To make it possible to download and upload, we must also write the code related to the request in the code related to the server, so that the operations related to uploading and downloading on the server can be performed correctly. To read more about this, you can visit the UPLOAD FILES section on node.js on the W3schools website. I put the code link on github.com related to the possibility of downloading and uploading to Todo-List
https://github.com/shokri1371/todo_upload-download_step4